# How to Transfer some Redis Data required to another file?

Tags: ubuntu, lua, server, redis

My Redis size has been 40 MB,
And there are a lot of mistakes,
And I need some saved information

How can I transfer some information to another file?
For example, transfer some dump.rdb data required to dump2.rdb

That way

redis:get( Data required )

redis2:set(......)